# Hibernate Postgresql boolean problems

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have object with boolean field like

@Entity

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private Boolean active = true;
}
```

AND query for creating

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS(
   ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   ACTIVE SMALLINT ,
   LOGIN  CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   NAME   CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PASSWORD CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   ROLE INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES ROLE(ID)
);
```

When i try to take a user object i have next exception ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint = boolean

Comment: Why do you use `smallint` if you want a `boolean`?

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL, `SMALLINT` maps to `Short` and `BOOLEAN` maps to `Boolean` (hence the name).

You get to decide whether to change the class or the table.

Answer (score 5):

try adding :

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
```